# How do I assert the response of the cy.request in cypress?

Tags: javascript, curl, cypress

I want to write a test that test the body of response

```
it('passes', () => {
    cy.request('POST',"localhost:8080", 
                 {
                   "body":"Hello World", 
                   "header": "Content-Type:application/json"
                 })
         assert that response body HELLO WORLD
              
    
  })
```

How do I assert the response body?
I curl following command will deliver response body

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8080 -d "Hello World"
HELLO WORLD%
```

Answer (score 4):

There's some examples in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#URL), for example

```js
cy.request('POST',"localhost:8080", {...})
  .its('body').should('include', 'HELLO WORLD%')
```

---

An live example for @jjhelguero

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  body: "Hello World", 
  header: "Content-Type:application/json"
})
.its('body')
.should('have.property', 'id', 101)
```

Comment: cy.request() yields at the response as an object with `status`, `body`, `headers`, and `duration` as properties so it should be `.its('response.body')`.

Comment: No, `its('body')` is shorthand for `.then(response => response.body)`.